# Getting "null object reference" error while trying to send an int with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

Code on sender Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScrollingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY", 1);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Code on receiver Activity

```
int a = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("KEY");
```

While trying this getting this error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

Can you help for fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The error message is telling you that the `int` is not being sent. Instead a `null` object is being picked up.

Comment: @MsYvette The possible duplicate has an excellent answer with 1000+ votes, which is valid for both Java and C#. The language and syntax might be different but the reason for exception and ways to debug it are very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error indicates that `getIntent` returns null reference, you should check where you are calling getIntent - it should be called inside or after `Actvity.onCreate` in Activity life cycle.